# nodejs request knowing when to retry

Tags: node.js, request

My internet is slow and unstable ( around 20KBPS during peak hours and may reach 400KBPS at 0100AM ~ 0400AM )...

So I will say that downloading something fail more often than it succeed. 
ECONNRESET happens almost everytime

All this limitation which brings me to think to use as less internet connection as possible..

My code is usually download and retry 2-3 times if it fails then leave it be and never return which is bad.

I want to know if some request with request library in nodejs may be retried and be successful. Something like 404 and ENOTFOUND  definitely won't need a retry while ECONNRESET will definitely  need one. I don't really have many clue on this.

So what conditions would prove that retrying may give a successful result ?
or perhaps what conditions would prove that retrying will definitely give no result ?

I found more thing to check like EAGAIN which probably mean a website is down but it exist...

Answer (score 1):

You can check the error object in the callback

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {

    if (error) {
      // retry logic
    }
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Print the google web page.
    }
})
```

Comment: My question is more to what to check rather than how to check it but if one explain to me both I would be grateful..

Comment: I know I know, I can check error.code and response.statusCode for that but I need to know what condition would certainly give knowledge that I can retry this and it can be successfully downloaded other than I mention in my question because I think the one I mention in the question is to narrow and there must be some other conditions that I miss.